# Running Angular in a mixed environment with server rendered pages

Tags: angular

In a project I am involved with we have an MVC5 App. We want to build complex front end javascripts components into this site using Angular 4. While still being able to render other parts with old school views.

My thought is that I would be able to create an app with different modules for the different areas and then be able to choose which of these are rendered in a specific location. But in all examples I have seen people are creating SPA applications and not building individual components or modules that are meant to be rendered by themselves.

I have used Angular JS alot and this allowed you to basically add the ng-app tag to the body, and then add angular controllers in the places you want to and you could easily mix this with server rendered pages.

I found this thread with people discussing the same thing, but noone seems to have a solution and their included plunker no longer works. https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/424nwn/using_angular_2_without_it_being_a_single_page_app/

How does one accomplish this with the new Angular 2+?

Answer (score 2):

Google "Angular Elements". Maybe some day it'll be as easy as one CLI command to wrap ng component as a custom element. But for now, Angular might not be the easiest to incorporate into a large server-rendered app.

One route which I took in a similar situation is I built a new NG SPA app and embedded legacy server views (which are also enriched with angularjs 1.x) in iframes. You read right, iframe! :D It just works. And I can gradually replace the old server views with new Angular sections, so ultimately the app will be a pure Angular spa.

Ie. there's a FrameComponent route, which takes the rest of the URL and sets that in an iframe's src, so any old url 'just works' inside the new app by just prepending the url. Some parameters added so eg. the server view skips rendering a menu etc.